# Error running openshift/origin docker: Error running 'chcon' to set the kubelet volume root directory SELinux context

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

When I run the openshift/origin [docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/openshift/origin/) , I see this error in logs of the container (`$ docker logs origin`).

`Error running 'chcon' to set the kubelet volume root directory SELinux context`

Is this a known issue or can it be ignored or did I miss anything?

The commandline I used is as 

`docker run -d --name "origin" -e "http_proxy=$http_proxy" -e "https_proxy=$https_proxy" -e "no_proxy=$no_proxy" --privileged --pid=host --net=host -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw  -v /sys:/sys openshift/origin start --cors-allowed-origins='.*'`

Some information of my OS and environment:

`3.12.28-4-default`


`SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12 (x86_64)
VERSION = 12
PATCHLEVEL = 0
NAME="SLES"
VERSION="12"
VERSION_ID="12"
PRETTY_NAME="SUSE Linux Enterprise Server 12"
ID="sles"`

Answer (score 1):

That error can be ignored unless you are trying to run with SELinux enabled. The container is trying to set the label on the volumes directory to ensure that labels are properly inherited.

Comment: Thanks. After that I get this error `E0112 06:06:27.807824    8713 fs.go:211] Stat fs failed. Error: EOF` for almost every second. Shall I also ignore them? And I assume I can ignore `"[ContainerManager] Failed to ensure state of "/docker-daemon": failed to move PID xxx (in "/system.slice/docker.service") to "/docker-daemon"`, since it looks like warning instead of Error.

Comment: Yes, that is a warning we generally consider "harmless" - there is work going on Kube right now to make the Kubelet respect systemd cgroups correctly and will fix this warning - that is slated for 1.2 Origin.  The Kubelet is trying to move the docker daemon into a cgroup so it can be resource controlled and monitored.