# Is the Openshift Origin Docker image production ready?

Tags: docker, openshift-origin

I would like to know if it is recommended to use that image in production environment. Or should I install Openshift Natively?

If I can use the docker image in production how should I upgrade it when a new version of image is released? I know I lose all configuration and application definition when starting a new docker container. Is there a way to keep them? Mapping volumes? Which volumes should be mapped?

The command line I am using is:

`$ sudo docker run -d --name "origin" \
        --privileged --pid=host --net=host \
        -v /:/rootfs:ro -v /var/run:/var/run:rw -v /sys:/sys -v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw \
        -v /var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes \
        openshift/origin start`

PS. There is [a relative question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716091/error-running-openshift-origin-docker-error-running-chcon-to-set-the-kubelet) I asked yesterday but not focusing on the same problem.

**Update on 20/01/2016**

I have tried @Clayton's suggestion of mapping folder `/var/lib/origin` which worked well before 17th Jan 2016. Then I started getting `Failed to mount` [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34870310/unable-to-deploy-router-or-registry-on-openshift-origin) when deploying router and some other applications. When I change it back to mapping `/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes`, it seems OK until now.

Answer (score 2):

If you have the `/var/lib/origin` directory mounted, when your container reboots you will still have all your application data.  That would be the recommended way to run in a container.

Comment: Hi @Clayton, I have updated the command line to match official tutorial so that it is more useful/applicable to others who may have similar question. Hopefully, your answer still applies. If it is the case, I will accept this as the answer. I am asking only because `/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes` is already mapped.

Comment: Just a further question, do you know why `-v /var/lib/docker:/var/lib/docker:rw` in the official tutorial? Docker cannot run inside container by only doing this in the latest version.

Comment: @Clayton could you go into the first part of the question please? I imagined installing using the 'advanced' method (red.ht/1l58sMF) is the proper way for production use. What are the downsides to using the all-in-one approach.

Comment: The ansible installer is currently our recommended way to install production OpenShift.  That currently has a mode for running in containers, but I don't believe yet has been tested against the 1.1 Origin images.  The regular path depends on RPMs which run as systemd services on the machines.

Comment: @Clayton when I follow your instruction (mapping the /var/lib/origin folder), it runs well. But when I enabled `--loglevel=5`, I have got `docker.go:368] Docker Container: /origin-448-log5 is not managed by kubelet.`. `origin-448-log5` is the container of a newer version. Is this normal?

Comment: I think it is normal after investigation. I have rerun it with cleaned `/var/lib/origin` and got the same log information.

Comment: @Clayton, it looks like the ansible installer requires REDHAT OS. Can it be used on SUSE Enterprise 12?

Comment: It has not been tested with SUSE to my knowledge.