# Unable to deploy router or registry on openshift origin

Tags: openshift-origin

Since yesterday, I have met some problems deploying applications and got [ImagePullBackOff error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34848422/how-to-debug-imagepullbackoff). Then when I recreated the container today, I found myself not able to deploy the router and registry any more. They used to work very stably.

The Error message I have got is as (for registry but same error for router):

`5:48:22 PM  docker-registry-1-deploy    Pod     FailedMount     Unable to mount volumes for pod "docker-registry-1-deploy_default": IsLikelyNotMountPoint("/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/fef8a925-be76-11e5-b607-005056b1164b/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/deployer-token-rlofq"): file does not exist (72 times in the last 11 minutes, 43 seconds)
5:48:22 PM  docker-registry-1-deploy    Pod     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: IsLikelyNotMountPoint("/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes/pods/fef8a925-be76-11e5-b607-005056b1164b/volumes/kubernetes.io~secret/deployer-token-rlofq"): file does not exist (72 times in the last 11 minutes, 43 seconds)`

It looks like some [related issues have been found in kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/18239) and there is a [workaround](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/pull/19069). But I wonder if and how can this be applied to Openshift Origin. Is the problem there only when running origin inside docker?

Comment: I have found a workaround. I used to  map `/root/origin:/var/lib/origin` when starting the container. When I change it back to `/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes:/var/lib/origin/openshift.local.volumes`, it seems OK now. I have no explanations on it, and will update once I have more information.

Comment: Changing it to `/var/lib/origin:/var/lib/origin` also seems good.